# Monogid4 Gridfs connection failure

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, carrierwave, gridfs

I'm working on Rails4, Mongoid4 and Gridfs. I;m not able to connect gridfs filesystem

```
class GridfsController < ApplicationController
  def serve
    gridfs_path = env["PATH_INFO"].gsub("/uploads/", "")
    begin
     gridfs_file = Mongo::GridFileSystem.new(Mongo::DB.new('database_name', Mongo::Connection.new('localhost'))).open(gridfs_path, 'r')
    self.response_body = gridfs_file.read
    self.content_type = gridfs_file.content_type
   rescue Exception => e
    self.status = :file_not_found
    self.content_type = 'text/plain'
    self.response_body = ''
    raise e
  end
 end
end
```

Getting this error

NameError (uninitialized constant GridfsController::Mongo):
app/controllers/gridfs_controller.rb:7:in `serve'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongoid doesn't use the "official" Ruby driver to talk to MongoDB and that's where [`Mongo::GridFileSystem`](http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/GridFileSystem.html) comes from. Mongoid uses [Moped](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/) to talk to MongoDB and Moped doesn't know anything about GridFS.

AFAIK the usual GridFS solution is to use [mongoid-grid_fs](https://github.com/ahoward/mongoid-grid_fs) to talk to GridFS:

```
self.response_body = Mongoid::GridFs[gridfs_path].data
```

or if you have the `id` instead of the path:

```
self.response_body = Mongoid::GridFs.get(gridfs_id).data
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of the gridfs specs for the Moped driver here: [moped-gridfs](http://goo.gl/7VwPVv)

It's better than loading two drivers (moped and mongo-ruby-driver)